# How can i change the bg color of an html file when clicking btns in the transparent swf file it contains

Tags: html, flash, background

I have a swf file with transparent bg. I publish it from flash to html and i want some sort of interactivity between the btns that i have there and the bg color of the html page which is visible behind that swf file. My knowledge in html is very little so i would appreciate answers with basic guidelines that a beginner can understand.
Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

When you click your button make it call:

```
getURL("javascript:changeClass(x);");
```

x will be a string with a color name. In your HTML have something like this in your javascript (assuming Jquery here):

```
function changeClass(x) {
   $('body').removeClass(); //Deletes all classes
   $('body').addClass(x); //Where x is a string
}
```

then in your CSS have a few classes for body:

```
body.red { background: red; }
body.green { background: green; }
body.blue { background: blue; }
```

so that calling one of those should change the color.

Comment: I hope when i add the getURL to the function of my btns everything else will be working fine, thank you Brian@Brian